# "Shared" linkage works on Linux, not on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, linkage

Given a big project, which generates an executable on both Linux and Windows architectures, I would like to take some classes (name it BigProjectClassA, BigProjectClassB and BigProjectClassC) to make a kind of plugin and modify the state of objects created from these three classes.

Hence, my tiny own project has code like this:

```
class TinyProjectExampleClass
{
   void modifyA(BigProjectClassA& a) {(...)}
   void modifyB(BigProjectClassB& b) {(...)}
   void modifyC(BigProjectClassC& c) {(...)}
   (...)
};
```

I'm building this code in order to generate a shared library (I'm coming from Linux background, so I don't know if this is the proper term for a DLL) which will be used within the big project.

When I try to build this on Linux, it is not necessary to link this code against the BigProjectClasses' object code and the big project gets correctly the expected state; however, Windows MSVC2013 linker complains with this error:

```
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl BigProjectClassX (...)"
```

How can I sort this out?

Comment: I don't know anything about Linux, but at least on Windows, when you build a dynamic/shared library (a DLL), you still get a stub LIB file. You need to specify that as an input to the linker when you build your application. That enables it to call functions from the DLL. But that `__cdecl` in the function signature is a bit concerning. Member functions of classes should use the `__thiscall` calling convention. Have you incorrectly annotated the function signature? I can't tell, the example code you showed is for an entirely different class.

Comment: You don't link it on linux but you pass the libs that has to be used to compile with `-L` and `-l` options. On windows is different  as @CodyGray already commented.

Comment: Google `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: Thank you all. Ok, if I get it, DLL is "needed" at runtime, and LIB at linking time (opposite to linux, which SO files are needed only at runtime). But the problem is that the big project is an executable, not a DLL. Are the LIB files built also when you are builing an exe file? AFAIK I can't "touch" the big project code only for this purpose. I think I'm not explaining quite well, apologies.

Comment: I've never done this (I was hoping someone who had would answer!) but I believe that you wouldn't use a LIB file in this case, you'd use `__declspec(dllexport)` or equivalent in the executable and `__declspec(dllimport)` or equivalent in the DLL.